# XIB not loading on iphone but in Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, xib

When I run my app in the simulator it does load the xib file and all looks perfectly fine. As soon as I run in on my iphone4 I get a white page with "My Universal App on iPhone" but not my xib file.

how comes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Clean all targets, delete Build folder and uninstall app from device.

Comment: I did it before but somehow now it worked :D Magic stuff going on here lol

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me once too. Try to clean your project (cmd+maj+K).

Try to use the function InitWithNibName:@"YourNibName" without misspelling in YourNiBName.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Check that the .xib file is still part of your project and set as a resource to copy at build time. This sort of thing tends to happen if you've removed a file from the build resources but there's still an old copy in the simulator's build directory.